# 'this application will be able to post tweets for you' how to achieve this?

Tags: php, twitter, authorization

I've created a twitter app (using PHP as the programming language) that requires the authorization from the users. This app has 'read and write' access. How do I tweet on my users behalf through this app. I've also searched a lot on the internet but to no avail. I'm a beginner and this is the first app that I've created. So I don't have much idea here.

Comment: and you already tried the documentation?

Comment: Yes. Nothing there. And plus their documentation is very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you use the OAuth 1.0A flow to obtain an access token representing the Twitter User's authorization of your application to work on their behalf.

Once you have this access token, you use it in OAuth 1.0A signed requests to Twitter's statuses/update API method, which is the API method that creates tweets. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update

It's best to use a library to perform these actions, such as tmhOAuth for PHP: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth

There are examples for negotiating tokens and tweeting using tmhOAuth here: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuthExamples

If you're new to OAuth, this guide is pretty helpful: http://oauthbible.com/